# Update the state of a dictionary using the Autocomplete component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Goal:

- I would like to update the state of my dictionary where the keys are the processPaths and the values are the selected values from the multi-select Autocomplete component from Material UI. Example shown below is what I would like my object to look like..

```
const myDesiredObject = {'role1': ['john', 'sally'], 'role2': ...}
```

I am able to get this to work with a basic Autocomplete component, but I am struggling to do it with a multi-select. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import {
  Autocomplete,
  Box,
  Button,
  Container,
  Grid,
  IconButton,
  Paper,
  Stack,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TextField,
  styled,
} from '@mui/material';
import { ChangeEvent, FunctionComponent, SyntheticEvent, useState } from 'react';

const rows = [
  { processPath: 'Role 1', headcount: 2 },
  { processPath: 'Role 2', headcount: 1 },
  { processPath: 'Role 3', headcount: 3 },
  { processPath: 'Role 4', headcount: 2 },
  { processPath: 'Role 5', headcount: 2 },
];

export const AccomodationsContent: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const associateOptions = ['john', 'kevin', 'sally', 'mark'];
  const [associateList, setAssociateList] = useState<Record<string, string[] | undefined>>({});

  const getAssociatesByProcessPath = (processPath: string): string[] => {
    return associateList[processPath] ?? [];
  };

  const handleSelection = (processPath: string, associates: string[]): void => {
    setAssociateList((prevAssociateList) => {
      return {
        ...prevAssociateList,
        [processPath]: associates,
      };
    });
  };

  console.log(associateList);

  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer component={Paper} sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Processes</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Employee Login</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
              <TableRow
                key={rowIndex}
                sx={{
                  '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 },
                }}>
                <TableCell style={{ width: '35%' }}>{row.processPath}</TableCell>
                <TableCell style={{ width: '45%' }} component='th' scope='row'>
                  <Autocomplete
                    multiple
                    id='emp-list'
                    options={employeesList}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} variant='standard' label='Employees' />}
                    onChange={(_, values) => handleSelection(processPath, values)}
                  />
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Made an edit, I am 90% of the way there. Just need to remove the empty array from the key, value pair when a name is deselected. I would prefer not use js and iterate if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "remove the empty array". Are you saying that when you unselect the people, it eventually turns into an empty array? To clarify: ```['john', 'sally']```, remove John and Sally from the list and the array ends up empty. I fail to see why that's an issue? Would you like to remove the entire object property from the desired object in that case?

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove the object property

Comment: You can do ```delete object.property``` simply make a condition around your case. So each time after your action, check if the array is empty, if it is, delete the property.